# Industry standard encryption on both Python 3 and Azure SQL database

Tags: python, sql, azure, wcf, encryption

I'm pretty good at Googling my programming needs, but could really not find this.

I'm finishing this security-related Python 3 application which runs on Raspberry Pi Zero W. Its data is in an Azure SQL DB and I reach it via a WCF service. Now it's time to protect data back and forth regardless of https implementation, so I tried hard to find an encryption mechanism supported on both worlds in such a way that I encrypt stuff in the device and decrypt it in Azure DB and the other way around. Since I could not find it I went ahead and developed an encryption mechanism based on the timestamp plus some partial scrambling but would appreciate if I could employ a real industry standard encryption scheme. It would benefit the product in many ways, really... So, has any of you guys been in this scenario, and if so, how did you proceed ? Does this make sense to you ?

Thanks very much.

-- Emilio

Comment: I'm curious to understand why beside https and SQL Azure encryption would you need to encrypt data in the client.

Comment: What does "regardless of https implementation" mean? Are you using HTTPS?

Comment: "Googling my programming needs", how interesting! It is a wonder we were able to accomplish anything with computer programming prior to Google. Why we must have read books and spent days/weeks studying. Now a little Google here, a little Google there, a snip-pit here a gist here, a Git clone, cobble it all together and there is a program that the author does not even understand. Undertstanding: over rated!

Comment: This will probably be used in environments where there may not be https implemented

Answer (score 0):

The industry standard for encrypting data is [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) (Advanced Encryption **Standard**), notice the word: Standard.